# Django model.objects.all() gives list index out of range upon calling it normally

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So im currently working on a private project using Django and when I try loading the page for the teams it just says "list index out of range" and im using object.all() to fetch every team from the model Team,

Inside the template im using a for loop to post each team on the page I've been trying using order_by() and first() but they didn't either seem to help.

My traceback is here http://dpaste.com/2S4Q7FY

What am I doing wrong here what should I change

### The view

```
def teams(request):
    teams = Team.objects.all()
    context = {
        'teams': teams,
    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        logged_in_user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=request.user.pk)
        context['logged_in_user'] = logged_in_user
    return render(request, 'teams.html', context)
```

### Model Team

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='teams/avatars', default='static/img/userpreload.png')
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='teams/backgrounds', default='static/img/userpreload.png')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    people_needed = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='TeamMembership')
    accepts_applications = models.BooleanField()

    @property
    def teamleaders_listable(self):
        leaders = self.members.filter(teammembership__leader=True)
        string = leaders[0].extendeduser.nickname

        for leader in leaders[1:]:
            string += ", " + leader.extendeduser.nickname

        return string

    @property
    def multiple_teamleaders(self):
        if len(self.members.filter(teammembership__leader=True)) > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Clearly `leaders` is empty thus `leaders[0]` throws an exception.

Comment: Its just funny because when using it on another django server its works fine but u maybe be right

Comment: Another thing, `len(self.members.filter(teammembership__leader=True))` force evaluates the entire queryset which might cause performance issues if the queryset is too large. You can use `.count()` instead which performs `SELECT COUNT(*)`: `self.members.filter(teammembership__leader=True).count() > 1`

Comment: Thanks for all the tips @OzgurVatansever I will take it with me :)
You both helped me really good thank u very much

Comment: @Alasdair `qs.exists()` is same as `qs.count() > 0` not `> 1`.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever of course it is. My mistake, I've deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part of the traceback is:

```
File "/home/melonendk/webapps/victory_genki_dk/victory/staff/models.py" in teamleaders_listable
  22.       string = leaders[0].extendeduser.nickname

File "/home/melonendk/webapps/victory_genki_dk/lib/python3.6/Django-1.11.6-py3.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in __getitem__
  289.         return list(qs)[0]

Exception Type: IndexError at /teams/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

This is telling you that `leaders[0]` is failing because `self.members.filter(teammembership__leader=True)` is an empty queryset.

You could change the code slightly to use `", ".join()` instead of looping through the queryset. This will return the empty string `''` when the queryset is empty.

```
@property
def teamleaders_listable(self):
    leaders = self.members.filter(teammembership__leader=True)
    return ", ".join(l.extendeduser.nickname for l in leaders)
```

Comment: Thank u very much you guys are basically my hero today :D